# Alarm Clock not giving expected output in C

Tags: c, clock

I'm currently making an alarm clock in C for my school, however I have two major issues:

1: The `printf` for the alarm never prints.

2: If I write the s should be anything higher than 50 then it starts printing negative values, or it goes to 0 and goes an entire 24 hours before it reaches the alarm (if I write a value instead of a, b and c, which you will see below:

I have printed the code below with the output I expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int h,m,s;
    int a,b,c;

    printf("Please write a time in the following format: hh:mm:ss \n");
    scanf("%d%d%d" ,&h,&m,&s);

    
    printf("Please state your alarm in the following format: hh:mm:ss ");
    scanf("%d%d%d \n" ,&a,&b,&c);
    
    
    start: ;
    for (h; h<24; h++) {
        for (m; m<60; m++) {
            for (s; s<60; s++) {
                if (a==h && b==m && c==s) {
                    printf("Alarm");
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    printf("%d:%d:%d \n" ,h,m,s);
                }
            }
            s=0;
        }
        m=0;
    }
    h=0;
    goto start;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Please write a time in the following format: hh:mm:ss
23:50:51
Please state your alarm in the following format: hh:mm:ss
23:50:54

23:50:52
23:50:53
ALARM
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should start with a **simpler program**, i.e. the **first scanf** followed by a `printf` of the values input... and *that's it*; then you would notice that *it does not work*, and then figure out how to fix *that*.

Comment: Completely agree with the previous comment. Don't try to write too much code at once and then scratch your head as to why it doesn't work. Write as little code as possible, get that working, and only then write some more code.

Comment: Here's a clue, `scanf("%d%d%d" ,&h,&m,&s);` should be `scanf("%d:%d:%d" ,&h,&m,&s);`. You describe the necessary format, but then you don't actually ask for it. Now make sure that works before you go any further.